# How to change background color of TR on hover?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to highlight the entire row of my table when user hovers over it. But only the TD changes background color instead of the entire row.

CSS:

```
.addItem_tr :hover{

background: blue;
```

}

Html

```
<table>
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th width="15%" ></th>
            <th width="35%" ></th>
            <th width="50%" ></th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr className="addItem_tr">
            <td className="td_add_serviced_item" >{item.quantity}</td>
            <td className="td_add_serviced_item" >{item.productID}</td>
            <td className="td_add_serviced_item" >{item.productInfo.productDescription}</td>
            </tr>
    <tr className="addItem_tr">
            <td className="td_add_serviced_item" >{item.quantity}</td>
            <td className="td_add_serviced_item" >{item.productID}</td>
            <td className="td_add_serviced_item" >{item.productInfo.productDescription}</td>
            </tr>
       
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

[image: Highlights only td]

Comment: That’s because you added a space in your CSS selector. That makes it a [Decsendant Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator), that’s why the TD gets highlid. Remove the space and it will work.